# Email not found in Database error message

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Good day everyone, Please I need your help. I have a password reset form that sent a reset link to users email if the email is a registered email in the database with "a success alert message ", but I noticed that unregistered email still display a success alert message instead of an error message(' user not found'). But when I test it on postman it shows success alert if the email is registered and error alert if not registered. I don't know where I got it wrong this my code below. Thanks.

**forgotPassword.ts**

```
async forgetPassword(){
   if(this.usernameEmail !==''){

    this.auth.resetPassword(this.usernameEmail).then( (res) =>{

      this.CFS.presentToast('Password reset link has been sent to your registered email. ', 'buttom',3000, 'success');

      this.route.navigate(['/login']);
    },
   (err) => {
      this.CFS.presentToast('Reset password fail, User not found', 'buttom',3000, 'danger');
      console.log(err)
    });
   } else{
    this.CFS.presentToast('Email address is required ', 'buttom',2000, 'danger');
   }

  }
```

**authservice.ts**

```
resetPassword(usernameEmail){

  let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  });

  this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}/api/forget_password.php?login=${usernameEmail}`;
  console.log('API URL for register a customer: ', this.apiUrl);

  return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl, {headers}).subscribe((successResp) => {
        resolve(successResp);

    },
    error => {
      resolve(error);  
      console.log('email not found',error) 
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: try console log this.usernameEmail in first line of forgetPassword?

Comment: Can u console. log(successResp) and share in question ? To take always same resut means you always enter subscribe. Then you may send your both success and not success result in subscribe

Comment: Check the status code of the failure response, it should not be 200. Then only it would go into your error block and print the required stuff. Basically **check your status code of the response** that you got from backend.

Comment: this is the message am having in my console 'HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://example.com/api/forget_password.php?login=example@gmail.com", ok: false, …}'  for both registered email or unregistered email. for the registered email I received a reset link

Comment: Are you taking 'email not found' in console for enregistered emails?

Comment: stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tepnm8